# Drawer on right side of screen?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new to Android development and wanted to know something. I'm using the navigation drawer for my application, but its on the left side. I want to know if there's a way to get it on the right side and how.

**activity_home.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<ListView

    android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

**drawer_list_item.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"

android:textColor="#fff"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

**fragment_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

My **Home.java**

```
package com.colourity.snatsh;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Home extends Activity {

// Within which the entire activity is enclosed
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

// ListView represents Navigation Drawer
private ListView mDrawerList;



// Title of the action bar
private String mTitle = "";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mTitle = "JAVATECHIG.COM";
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

    // Getting reference to the DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);




    // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), 
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menus));

    // Setting the adapter on mDrawerList
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Enabling Home button
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // Enabling Up navigation
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Setting item click listener for the listview mDrawerList
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // Getting an array of rivers
            String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menus);

            // Currently selected river
            mTitle = menuItems[position];

            // Creating a fragment object
            WebViewFragment rFragment = new WebViewFragment();

            // Passing selected item information to fragment
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putInt("position", position);
            data.putString("url", getUrl(position));
            rFragment.setArguments(data);


            // Getting reference to the FragmentManager
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            // Creating a fragment transaction
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            // Adding a fragment to the fragment transaction
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, rFragment);

            // Committing the transaction
            ft.commit();

            // Closing the drawer
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        }
    });
}

protected String getUrl(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return "http://javatechig.com";
    case 1:
        return "http://javatechig.com/category/android/";
    case 2:
        return "http://javatechig.com/category/blackberry/";
    case 3:
        return "http://javatechig.com/category/j2me/";
    case 4:
        return "http://javatechig.com/category/sencha-touch/";
    case 5:
        return "http://javatechig.com/category/phonegap/";
    case 6:
        return "http://javatechig.com/category/java/";
    default:
        return "http://javatechig.com";
    }
}



/** Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */

public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: As you said it's already on the left side, so what is the problem?

Comment: I meant right. Sorry. @EmilAdz

Comment: take a look at my answer : )

Comment: Drawer on a right side is an antipattern. Try to avoid doing such things.

Answer (score 0):

Well as the documentation states:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html

> Drawer positioning and layout is controlled using the android:layout_gravity attribute on child views corresponding to which side of the view you want the drawer to emerge from: left or right. (Or start/end on platform versions that support layout direction.)

So yes you can put it no the right side as well using the `android:layout_gravity` property : )

Comment: So just add `android:layout_gravity` to my xml file?

Comment: Yes, to the DrawerLayout object in your xml file

Comment: I don't have a drawerlayout object. I edited my question and added my code to it.

Comment: what do you mean? you are doing this in the code:     mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); it means that you have drawer_layout in the xml file. just add the gravity property to it

Comment: It's not in any of my xml files. I posted them above. Can you see ` mDrawerLayout` in my XML?

Comment: yes it's the first one in the activity_home layout: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

Comment: Alright, thank you for being patient with me. I get this error, now. `Attribute name "android:layout_gravity" associated with an element type "android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" must be followed by the ' = ' 
 character.`

Comment: yes, I think so... I have never done it before... if this doesn't work you can try to place this attribute to the frame layout child of the DrawerLayout